# Question about open drain

Tags: mosfet, open-drain

In which region does a NMOS work when its drain is open circuit? Let's say the input is high voltage lavel, how can I determine whether it is saturation of triode region when drain is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the drain is completely open, there's no current :-) You need to think about a load on the OD = e.g. a pull-up resistor or a constant current source. Maybe your reasoning can take off from there.

Comment: If I do not have a load, will the open circuit voltage be equal to ground when I have a high voltage input?

Comment: Yes, definitely. If your "source" electrode is grounded, that is the only reference point of such a circuit (with "drain" floating free). So whatever finite resistance you end up having between D and S, the free-floating D will gravitate to S.